# Condition in rows, modify all columns without a loop

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, rows

what I want to do is to modify all selected columns of an R data table according to the rows conditions i.e[image]

for all 4 columns selected in cols variable, if the value is greater (or equal) than 1.5, i would like to put them to 1 else 0

I tried something like that : `iris[(cols) > 1.5 , (cols) := 1, .SDcols = cols]`

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One `data.table` approach:

```r
iris <- as.data.table(iris)
cols <- names(iris)[1:4]
cols
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
iris[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(z) fifelse(z > 1.5, 1, z)), .SDcols = cols]
iris
#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#             <num>       <num>        <num>       <num>    <fctr>
#   1:            1           1          1.4         0.2    setosa
#   2:            1           1          1.4         0.2    setosa
#   3:            1           1          1.3         0.2    setosa
#   4:            1           1          1.5         0.2    setosa
#   5:            1           1          1.4         0.2    setosa
#   6:            1           1          1.0         0.4    setosa
#   7:            1           1          1.4         0.3    setosa
#   8:            1           1          1.5         0.2    setosa
#   9:            1           1          1.4         0.2    setosa
#  10:            1           1          1.5         0.1    setosa
#  ---                                                            
# 141:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 142:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 143:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 144:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 145:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 146:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 147:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 148:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 149:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
# 150:            1           1          1.0         1.0 virginica
```

An alternative using `set`:

```r
for (nm in cols) set(iris, which(iris[[nm]] > 1.5), nm, 1)
```

Comment: I think my edit does that.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

iris[,1:4] %>% data.table() %>% mutate_all(~ ifelse(.x>=1.5,1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check for numeric columns across can be a good fit, it also works with more specific choices like positions and names

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris |>
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(across(.cols = where(is.numeric),.fns = ~ if_else(.x > 1.5,1,.x)))
#> # A tibble: 150 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1            1           1          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2            1           1          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3            1           1          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4            1           1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5            1           1          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6            1           1          1           0.4 setosa 
#>  7            1           1          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8            1           1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9            1           1          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10            1           1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Base R option -

```
data <- iris
cols <- 1:4
data[cols] <- +(data[cols] > 1.5)

#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1              1           1            0           0     setosa
#2              1           1            0           0     setosa
#3              1           1            0           0     setosa
#4              1           1            0           0     setosa
#5              1           1            0           0     setosa
#6              1           1            1           0     setosa
#...
#...
```

The `+` at the beginning is used to change the logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) to integers (1/0).

Answer (score 0):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
     mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ +(. > 1.5)))
```